# Access one row in an array PHP

Tags: php, sql, arrays, sql-server, rows

I have this while loop in php:

```
<?php while($percentSKU = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultSKU, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) : ?>
    <p><?php echo $percentSKU['PercentageSales']; ?>%</p>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Which out puts 12 rows, for example:

.00%, .00%, .00%, .00%, 26.22%, .00%, 3.96%, 1.49%, 5.23%, 20.88%, 42.22%, .00%

Is there a way to only print out 1 particular row?

I have tried things like this:

```
<?php echo $percentSKU['PercentageSales'][4]; ?>
```

But because the the array returns a sting, I am getting the nth single character not the nth row of data. 
So instead of getting '26.22' im am getting '2'

Any ideas?

Comment: What about just use echo $percentSKU['PercentageSales']? I'm not sure as I can't see how the array looks like. Could you use print_r($precentSKU['PercentageSales']); and show us the output?

Comment: What is the condition for choosing the row to output?

Comment: <?php print_r($percentSKU['PercentageSales']); ?> just gives me '.00%' which i am assuming is just giving me the first row...

Comment: I'm confuse why it's  12 rows not cols? what's your table structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is returning a string you can convert it to an array and access it via its index. To convert a string to an array you can use the **explode** function.

for ex :

```
$string = '.00%, .00%, .00%, .00%, 26.22%, .00%, 3.96%, 1.49%, 5.23%, 20.88%, 42.22%, .00%';

$result = explode(',' $string);
$finalvalue = $result[0];
```

**Note :** The $result[0] will return the first value of the string, you will have to set the index which you require.

Comment: Thanks that is great! So if i was to take this one step further and make $string = $percentSKU['PercentageSales'];
to make it dynamic how would i go about doing that because i don't get any output with that at the moment. would i need to be wrapped in a loop?

Comment: Try doing var_dump to the $percentSKU['PercentageSales']; variable and try to find are you getting the value in your $resultSKU first or not.

Comment: var_dump gives me this: string(3) ".00"

Comment: Yes..so that means you are getting the value.. try doing print_r($yourvariable) and then choose the index whose value you require and echo it.

Answer (score 0):

working with mysql I use that function:

```
function ExecuteQuery_assocArray($query) 
{
  $result = mysqli_query($this->link, $query);
  $set = array();
  while ($set[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)); 
  return $set;
}
```

it returns $set of rows

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment, but i am using SQL Server not MySQL so unfortunately this wouldn't be usable for myself.

Comment: @PHPNewbie, but you didn't specify on your question nor on your tag that you're using SQL server.

Comment: @Ronald, i did but someone edit my question to remove the tag.